# jquery post request no success

Tags: jquery, post, request

i hope someone can help me.

I have this function to post some login data to an external system.

```
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
              url:"https://www.europace2.de/partnermanagement/login.do",
              type:"POST",
              contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
              data:{ username: "username", password: "password" },
              dataType: 'html',
              success: function (data) {
                     $(".test").html(data);             
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert("something went wrong");
                }
            })  
        });
```

The Status is 200 OK but i didn't get any answer and the success fails also.

Here i have a part of the documentation from the external system.

**Request**

POST

```
https://www.europace2.de/partnermanagement/login.do?
redirectTo=%2FvorgangsManagementFrontend

Header:
Content­‐type:application/x-­www-­form-­urlencoded;charset=UTF-­‐8

Body (Form Data URLencoded):
username=Mustermann@beispiel.de&password=4711

The parameter redirectTo is optional...anyway with that it works not at all.
```

**Reponse**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-­‐Type:text/plain
Set-­‐Cookie:sessionId=3

f8a86fa02128b5265de9f1ec4b3c4be; Path=/
```

At dataType i tried xml, json, script, text, html and just no dataType.

So... anybody has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I don't know is it allowed. If someone want to look by himself whats happen i can give username and passwort via private message.

Comment: [Edit]: My previous comment was incorrect. Sorry. Can you explain what exactly the external script does?

Comment: I made an edit to the previous comment. Btw how could you say that the success fails? As far as I can see, there's no response body from the external server. It just sets a cookie. Check if that's set. You can do so, by executing document.cookie in the console. The cookie sessionId should be present. alternatively you can execute 
(document.cookie).indexOf('sessionId') and check the response.

Comment: Yes it set a cookie. But actually it should login to the external system. No i don't know what exactly the external script does. I thing its just a login. I expected any kind of string or a page at the response :/

Comment: I suggest you completely read into the documentation or whatever's provided before making requests to the site. And if it's not from any trusted source, I suggest you write your own code and login authenticator.

Comment: actually what i posted is the main part of the documentation :D

Comment: Do not include untrusted 3rd party scripts as a part of your application. It's very very risky considering the amount of damage they can do.